# Cannot get this code to work, simple Python else if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

## When I run the code below I keep getting a syntax error and it is highlighted where shown.

```
sf_population, sf_area = 864816, 231.89
rio_population, rio_area = 6453682, 486.5

sf_area = (int(sf_area))
rio_area = (int(rio_area))

def x= sf_population/sf_area
def y= rio_population/rio_area

if x<y:
    print"True"
if x>y:
    print"False"
```

Comment: That's not how `def` works.

Comment: Sure thing: `def x = stuff` is a syntax error.

Comment: Why did you even put `def` there, anyway?

Comment: Yes, so why do you keep writing invalid syntax?

Comment: Also, they should be print("True") and print("False")

Comment: @ZiyaERKOC this `print` statement works, at least in Python <= 2.7

Comment: @galfisher Thank you then :D

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Much appreciated, now I feel dumb. :)

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
sf_population, sf_area = 864816, 231.89
rio_population, rio_area = 6453682, 486.5

sf_area = int(sf_area)
rio_area = int(rio_area)

x = sf_population/sf_area
y = rio_population/rio_area

if x < y:
    print"True"

if x > y:
    print"False"
```

Answer (score 0):

`def` is used in python to define functions, not variables. To set the value of `x` to `sf_population/sf_area` simply drop the `def` in lines 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
sf_population, sf_area = 864816, 231.89
rio_population, rio_area = 6453682, 486.5

sf_area = (int(sf_area))
rio_area = (int(rio_area))

x = sf_population/sf_area 
y = rio_population/rio_area

if x<y:
    print "True"
if x>y:
    print "False"
```

Unless you want to define a function, there is no need for `def`
Beside of this, consider using `elif` for the second condition

```
if x<y:
    print "True"
elif x>y:
    print "False"
```